# Can you give a example about "the containing block is established by the page area in the case of paged media"

Tags: html, css

I have no idea about [`page area` (see 10.1 number 3)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details), because I haven't had these experiences! I think paged media is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Pages), [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/#continuous-media) and print function in browser.

Is page area like document viewport? How does it established "containing block"?

In addition, I read [2. Choosing A Positioning Scheme: position property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#ref-for-valdef-position-fixed), so, maybe I know a little about `fixed` feature.

Finally, can you give me a completely example? It's better to be run, although containing block is an abstract concept!

Comment: Paged media is any media that is typically presented in pages. The viewport is not a page. The browser is page-less or can be seen as a single, long page. Printing is the most common form of paged media.

Comment: You have two questions here. Only ask one question in each ask. If you have several questions, post them separately.